# Word Macro Search & Replace formating issue

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to build a macro (as a noob) to find certain words and then change the formatting for that word (i.e. make it bold or italic)

This code 'sort of works.' It will find some words and change them but not change others. The weird thing is it works until I add another sub then it stops formatting on some words, while formatting others. The routine never breaks and runs until the end without error.

Can anyone teach why this is happening and what I am doing wrong? I am not a programmer. Thanks

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Printer"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Replacement.Font.bold = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Parameter Values"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Replacement.Font.bold = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Use All Applicants Indicator"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Replacement.Font.bold = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Next Section"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Replacement.Font.bold = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would program the search macro as a separate sub, like this.

```
Private Sub FindAndReplace(ByVal Txt As String, _
                           Optional ByVal NewTxt As String, _
                           Optional ByVal Fmt As Boolean = False, _
                           Optional ByVal BldFmt As Boolean = False)

    With ActiveDocument.Content
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = Txt
            .Format = Fmt Or BldFmt

            With .Replacement
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = NewTxt
                .Font.Bold = BldFmt
            End With
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

All the optional parameters you may use but don't have to.
Then I would call the sub repeatedly with different parameters, perhaps like this:-

```
Sub MakeReplacements1()

    FindAndReplace "Printer", BldFmt:=True
    FindAndReplace "Parameter values", BldFmt:=True
    FindAndReplace "Use All Applicants Indicator", BldFmt:=True
    FindAndReplace "Next Section", BldFmt:=True
End Sub
```

or even like this:-

```
Sub MakeReplacements2()

    Dim Fnd() As String
    Dim i As Long

    Fnd = Split("Printer|Parameter values|Use All Applicants Indicator|Next Section", "|")
    For i = 0 To UBound(Fnd)
        FindAndReplace Fnd(i), BldFmt:=True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`Selection` is an object comprising the part of the document currently selected.
`Find` is a property of the `Selection` object defining the `Find` object (same name but one is a property, the other an object). The `Find` object has properties such as `Text`, `Forward`, `Wrap`, etc. and it has methods like `ClearFormatting` or `Execute`. All of this you can read up in the MSDN library.

Now, when you define the `Find` object you are describing something you want to find. With the `Execute` command you start looking for it. Your code is missing this command in some places.

The search is limited to the `Selection`. If you have selected nothing Word will presume you want to search the whole document. But `Selection.Find` will change the Selection to highlight the found item. Therefore, if you want to continue searching the whole document you would need to reset the Selection after each search with, for example, `Activedocument.Content.Select`.

In a nutshell, if you clear the `Find` object after each use, set a new description before each repeated use, define the `Selection` object for each search and don't forget to `Execute` each separate search your code should work just as you intend it to work.

Comment: Adding the execute worked. Thank you. However I am sure there has to be a cleaner method of doing this. I am trying to read but MSDN documents don't make sense to me. Thanks though.